# Missing something in a simple derivation of the Double Negation rule via the Negation Introduction Rule.

Tags: logic, soft-question, first-order-logic

I quote Shapiro's entry on Classical Logic ( in SEP) where (As) refers to a " rule of assumptons" :

(As) If ϕ is a member of Γ, then Γ⊢ϕ.

> Our next clauses are for the negation sign, “¬”. The underlying idea
> is that a sentence ψ is inconsistent with its negation ¬ψ. They cannot
> both be true. We call a pair of sentences ψ,¬ψ contradictory
> opposites. If one can deduce such a pair from an assumption θ, then
> one can conclude that θ is false, or, in other words, one can conclude
> ¬θ
>
> (¬I)If Γ1,θ⊢ψ and Γ2,θ⊢¬ψ, then Γ1,Γ2⊢¬θ
>
> **By (As), we have that {A,¬A}⊢A and {A,¬A}⊢¬A. So by ¬I we have that
> {A}⊢¬¬A**. However, we do not have the converse yet. Intuitively, ¬¬θ
> corresponds to “it is not the case that it is not the case that” . One
> might think that this last is equivalent to θ, and we have a rule to
> that effect...

I see easily how both $A$ and $\neg A$ are derivable by the (As) rule from the set $\{A, \neg A\}$ , but I cannot see how it follows from this that $\{A\}⊢¬¬A$.

That is, I do not understands in which way $\{A\}$ plays the role of the set union $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ in the statement of the rule just before . I even do not understand what plays the role of $\Gamma_1$, nor of $ \Gamma_2$, nor of $ \theta$.

> What substitutions should be done in order to recognize clearly in
> this proof an instantiation of the negation introduction rule?

Comment: Take $\Gamma_1 := \{A\}$, $\Gamma_2 := \{A\}$, $\theta := \neg A$ and $\psi := A$. Then you have $\Gamma_1,\theta \vdash \psi$ since $\{A, \neg A\} \vdash A$, and $\Gamma_2, \theta \vdash \neg \psi$ since $\{A, \neg A\} \vdash \neg A$. Thus, you can conclude $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \neg \theta$, which is $\{A\} \vdash \neg\neg A$ as expected.

Comment: Indeed.  Let $\Gamma_1=\{A\}$ and $\Gamma_2=\{A\}$, then you will have $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2=\{A\}$.  $$\small\begin{split}\Gamma_1,\theta&\vdash \varphi\\\Gamma_2,\theta&\vdash \neg\varphi\\\hline\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2&\vdash \neg\theta\end{split}\qquad\begin{split}\color{silver}\{A\color{silver}\},\neg A&\vdash A\\\color{silver}\{A\color{silver}\},\neg A&\vdash \neg A\\\hline\color{silver}\{A\color{silver}\}&\vdash \neg\neg A\end{split}$$

Comment: Alternatively, let $\Gamma_1=\{A\}$ and $\Gamma_2=\{\}$, then you will have $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2=\{A\}$.  $$\small\begin{split}\Gamma_1,\theta&\vdash \varphi\\\Gamma_2,\theta&\vdash \neg\varphi\\\hline\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2&\vdash \neg\theta\end{split}\qquad\begin{split}\color{silver}\{A\color{silver}\},\neg A&\vdash A\\\color{silver}\{\color{silver}\},\neg A&\vdash \neg A\\\hline\color{silver}\{A\color{silver}\}&\vdash \neg\neg A\end{split}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek to have $\{A\}$ be the union of two sets.  At least one must be $\{A\}$, the other may be $\{A\}$ or $\{\}$.

You seek to derive $A$ from $\neg A$ and one of the above sets (call it $\Gamma_1$).  Since, $A$ cannot derive from $\neg A$ and the emptyset, but is trivially derived from $\{A\}$, the later is what that set shall be.$$\{A\}, \neg A\vdash A$$

You also seek to derive $\neg A$ from $\neg A$ and the other of the above sets (call it $\Gamma_2$); and as either $\{A\}$ or $\{\}$ works... we may use either.$$\{\},\neg A\vdash\neg A$$

So there we go $$\begin{split}\Gamma_1,\theta&\vdash \varphi\\\Gamma_2,\theta&\vdash \neg \varphi\\\hline \Gamma_1,\Gamma_2&\vdash \neg\theta\end{split}\qquad\begin{split}A,\neg A&\vdash A\\\neg A&\vdash \neg A\\\hline A&\vdash \neg\neg A\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks for this student friendly answer!